# ui-router resolve function not returning data to angular component

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

First angular component with angular-ui-router.  The page loads but there is no data. Console.log in the service .then shows the data is an array of 21 elements. Seems so simple, tearing my hair out-

stateProvider:

```
    $stateProvider

    .state('home', {
        template: '<prospects-home resource-data ="$resolve.resourceData"></prospects-home>',
        resolve: {
            resourceData: function  (dataService) {
                return dataService.getResources();
            }
        }
    })
```

Component:

```
     angular
        .module("myApp")
        .component('prospectsHome', {
            templateUrl: '/Scripts/partials/partial-home.html',
            bindings: {
                resourceData: '=',
            },
            controller: function() {
                var $ctrl = this;
                $ctrl.resources = resourceData;
            }
        })
```

Template:

```
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="resource in $ctrl.resources">
                    <td>{{ resource.firstName }}, {{ resource.lastName }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Service:

```
    var app = angular.module("myApp");
    app.service('dataService', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {
        return {
            getResources: function () {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                return $http.get('/Scripts/data/resources.json')
                .then(function (response) {
                   console.log(response.data);
                   deferred.resolve(response.data);
                });
                return deferred.promise;
            }
        }
    }]);
```